# Data Access Array Binding -- When Errors Happen In Batch?

Tags: c#, arrays, oracle, binding

I have code in C# that is using the Oracle Data Access provider and preforming array binding on multiple INSERT statements.  I have this code working.  However, when I set my batch count to 1000, and out of the 1000 inserts, one of them fail, it appears that the other 999 good records are not committed to the database.

Is there a way, using the array binding, to commit the transactions that are successful, and only reject the ones that are not successful in the batch?

Comment: Insert Into MyTable(Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7) Values { :1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7);
cmd.Parameters.Add("1", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = decV_1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("2", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = sV_2;
cmd.Parameters.Add("3", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = decV_3;
cmd.Parameters.Add("4", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = decV_4;
cmd.Parameters.Add("5", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = decV_5;
cmd.Parameters.Add("6", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = sV_6;
cmd.Parameters.Add("7", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = sV_7;
cmd.ArrayBindCount = iBatchMax;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting of the above code.  This is just to show what I am attempting to do with the code.  This all works as long as one of the elements in the array does not have incorrect data.  I have tried to clean the data in the array before doing the inserts.  I just am looking for a way, when the batch count is set higher than one, to get the valid records to commit in the batch rather than all of the batch being rejected.